# What will happen if i suspend my OpenStack admin user?

Tags: openstack

Did someone have been trying to do something like that, to suspend ( deactivate ) the admin account and continue working with openstack on another account?

I have an OpenStack version 2.3.1 ( do not ask why :D ) installed on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Normally you assign the admin role to the accounts belonging to your OpenStack administrators or even better to the members of an administrator  group. Then cloud operators log in with their personal and individual accounts and they don't actually log in anymore with the "admin " account. Then track if logins stil occur and from where before you disable it. AFAIK the account is not normally needed to keep OpenStack operational , but I might be mistaken. We only keep it for whenever AD integration breaks.

Comment: I doubt that anyone still remembers what the behavior in Grizzly Keystone was :-).  But the current Keystone behavior is that the **name** of the account doesn't have any deep significance.  The real issue is whether there are any enabled accounts with the 'Admin' role.  If you disabled the last account with the 'Admin' role, you might not be able to enable it again.

Comment: @StephenC Thank you.

Anyone else can give opinion about the subject